# JavaScript showing undefined

Tags: javascript, html

Following code is showing `undefined` in alert messages on clicking the radio buttons. What is the problem with the code?

The console error showing that `pwdissue` is `undefined`.

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
   <head>
    <% String loginstatus=request.getParameter("loginstatus"); %>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>LOGIN PAGE</title>
    <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
```

```
        function pwd(){
            var a=pwdissue.value;
            alert(a);
        }
        function validate(uname,pwd){
            var username,password;
            username=uname.value;
            password=pwd.value;
            if(username=="" && password==""){
                alert("Please enter your username and password");
            }else if(username=="")
                alert("Username filed shouldn't be empty");
            else if(password=="")
                alert("Password filed shouldn't be empty");
            else{
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

```
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
    java
        <div style="border-bottom:1px solid #DEDEDE; border-left:1px solid #DEDEDE; width:1090px;">
             <div class="heading-bg">SALES FORCE TRACKING SYSTEM</div>
            <div class="main">
                <%if(loginstatus!=null && loginstatus.equals("mismatch")){
                    %><h1 class="errormessage">INVALID USERNAME OR PASSWORD.</h1><%
                }%>
               <form name="loginform" onsubmit="return validate(uname,pwd,passwordissues)" action="loginpagevalidation.jsp">
                        <table name="logintable">
                            <caption>SignIn Here</caption>
                            <tr><td>UserName</td><td><input type="text" name="uname" /></td></tr>
                            <tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="password" name="pwd"/></td></tr>
                            <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="SIGNIN"/><input type="reset" onclick="managersigning.html" name="reset" value="RESET"/></td></tr>
                            <tr><td></td><td><a href="signuppage.html"> Click here to SingUp</a></td></tr>
                       <!--     <tr><td></td><td>Forget Password ?<a href="passwordrecovery.jsp">Click here</a></td></tr> -->
                        </table>
                </form>
                    <input type="radio" name="pwdissue" onclick="javascript:pwd()" value="forget"/>Forget Password
                    <input type="radio" name="pwdissue" onclick="javascript:pwd()" value="reset"/>Reset Password
            </div>
        </div>
   </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change both `onclick` to be this instead:

```
onclick="javascript:pwd(this)"
```

Then change the function to:

```
function pwd(sender) {
        var a = sender.value;
        alert(a);
}
```

The radio button name is not part of the global context, the browser won't find it for you so most simple approach is passing the object itself to the function.

Answer (score 5):

```
    function pwd(o){
        var a=o.value;
        alert(a);
    }

    <input type="radio" name="pwdissue" onclick="pwd(this)" value="forget"/>
```